# Is this Dataset somehow skewed?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-engineering, churn

I am working on a dataset that has 100K points, it's about Customer churn. So I don't know whether this dataset is skewed, incomplete or what. I tried doing some feature engineering on it but couldn't get any further. I tried fitting the data to multiple models, but the performance I am getting is terrible. I just think there are not enough features to get a better performance(I maybe wrong). Any nudge in the right direction would be very much appreciated.
I am attaching some snapshots of the data. If you need more info about it, drop a comment.
What sort of Feature engineering and data preprocessing needs to be done here? I'd be glad if someone helped me out here.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Update:
I tried using XGBClassifier and found much-increased performance, is there any parameter tuning that I can do to get a further improved performance?**

[image]

Comment: Try using HistGradientBoosting classifier https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.HistGradientBoostingClassifier.html

Comment: I tried using it but wasn't able to see any increase in performance. Is there any feature engineering that needs to be done before trying to fit it into any model?

Answer (score 0):

One of the data aspects that affect model accuracy, depending on the model, is variance. This is usually corrected by performing standardization or normalization of your features using various methods such as those found [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.preprocessing).

The other one is converting your categorical variables to numeric values through encoding, also found in the link above. Another method is using the Pandas get_dummies method.

Also, removing outliers from your data could help.